# Android lifecytle of thread started from activity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity

When I start regular endless Java thread from Activity I see this thread still running even
when the activity destroyed pressing back button or calling by Finish()
from the activity.
The thread stops when I force destroy the application.
My question is if Android destroys this thread in some condition or it will run forever?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread will terminate if :

1. Parent process is closed, killed. *(Android OS can do this any time, user can do it in settings)*
2. Is explicitly Interrupted, and interrupt is not handled. *(during blocking IO operations)*
3. Run methods returns. *( good coding :) )*
4. Some un-handled exception surfaces. *( possible )*

Comment: When parent process is killed?

Comment: @CostaMirkin When Android decides it doesn't need the app running. Or when user force-stops it from Settings.

Comment: Thanks :)
As I understand if thread is created in service Android can't kill the service

Answer (score 1):

Android will destroy if it needs memory for other processes to run and as this would be background process and running from long time.